# Saving Context At a Later Stage - Saving Pointer To Context ? Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I have the following code which inserts a new entity into a Core Data model (via Magical Record) :

```
- (void)insertWithData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary {

DLog(@"Inserting %@", [_entityClass description]);

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];

id entity = [_entityClass createInContext:context];

[entity setValuesFromDictionary:dataDictionary];

if ([entity isKindOfClass:[Syncable class]]) {
    [entity setValue:YesNumber forKey:@"syncedToServer"];
}

[context save];
}
```

As this code runs multiple times in a FOR loop called from another class, I would like to only save the context once the loop has completed to optimise performance.

My question is what is the best way to do this ? Should I save a reference to the context here (e.g in the app delegate) and then save using this reference in the calling class ? Or can I just call NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrent Thread again in the calling class and use this reference  - i.e in the calling class :

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];
[context save];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can save context after loop. It's much better than save in each iteration. If you'll take a look into MagicalRecord src, you'll see that `MR_contextForCurrentThread` returns always same context for same threads, if there's no context for thread MagicalRecord creates it.
Also, you don't need to pass context `[_entityClass createInContext:context]`, just `[_entityClass MR_createEntity]` - it will be created on current thread's context

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. First, contextForCurrentThread is now deprecated. It is already removed in MagicalRecord 3.0, so now is the time to get used to NOT using it. You were doing ok to specify a context, but instead you should use a confinement context, and either make the default context the parent, or have it observe changes from your new context, and merge those in on save.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    // your for loop
}];
```

Please read http://saulmora.com/2013/09/15/why-contextforcurrentthread-doesn-t-work-in-magicalrecord/ for more information about why you shouldn't use contextForCurrentThread.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to save at the end of the loop, I suggest passing in your NSManagedObjectContext as a parameter:

```
- (void) insertData:(id)data inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
{
   //do all your data stuff here.

}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_confinementContext];
for (id obj in objCollection)
{
   [self insertData:obj inContext:context];
}
[context MR_save];
```